# iOS | Swift | Date formatting | What is going wrong?

Tags: ios, swift5, iso8601, dateformatter

We are getting dates in GMT from server. While parsing we used dateDecodingStrategy as iso8601. We are also getting a specific timezone string from server. We need to consider that timezone and convert the GMT date to be specific to that timezone.

```
private func dateInUserTImeZone(date: Date) -> Date {
         //userSessionTImeZone is the TimeZone received from server.
        let timezoneOffset =  userSessionTImeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: date)
        let epochDate = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        let timezoneEpochOffset = epochDate + Double(timezoneOffset)
        let updatedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timezoneEpochOffset)
        return updatedDate
    }
```

**Date after converting to the timezone (CST) received from server --> 2021-02-12 03:18:54 +0000 using above function wherein we passed the iso8601 date created via parsing of JSON response**

//Below code is for applying formatting to the above date.

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter(dateFormat: "MMMdd", useTemplate: true)
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(dateFormatTemplate)
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = isRelative
let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date) //** date is 2021-02-12 03:18:54 +0000**
```

We are getting value in strDate as Feb 11 instead of Feb 12

What is going wrong here and how it can be resolved? Converting date to a specific timezone is a requirement for doing other calculations as well.

Comment: Do you really need to move the timestamp by adding/subtracting seconds, or do you simply need to interpret one timestamp in different timezones? I'm suspecting the latter, and in that case you should simply use a `DateFormatter` with the specific timezone.

Comment: @Gereon, the formatted date string generation comes in the end. Prior to that I need to compare the date received from server with current date. So I converted both of these dates in that timezone first and perform comparisons. For one of the result of comparison , I am making use of date formatter to get date string in "MMM dd" format.

Comment: No, you're not "converting" these dates, you're changing them to some other dates. Like @gnasher729 says in their answer, `Date` has no concept of a timezone, it's simply a fixed point in time. All you need to do to compare is parse the server response (including it's timezone info) and compare it to `Date()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "dates in some time format" in iOS. A Date is a point in time. It doesn't have a time zone at all.

Text can describe a date in a time zone dependent way. That's what you have as input: You have a string, and you were told it's a string in GMT. So you use a DateFormatter with the correct settings for GMT to convert the string into a Date. You NEVER change that date. You can use another DateFormatter with the correct settings for the user to convert the Date to a string in the user's timezone.

BTW. There is absolutely no need to add seconds to a Date by calling timeIntervalSince1970. There's a method to add seconds directly to a Date. There are also methods to add minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, years to a Date; these need a Calendar object because what adding "a month" means depends on the calendar.